# How to plot multiple box plot in one box plot in one in r studio?

Tags: charts

I am new here.

I want to produce the something similar, exactly like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph 
 but using my data. my data has a lot of information, 38 household's environment data measuring for Pm2.5, temperature etc etc. I want to plot the box plot for every household (winter and summer, if possible). it will be great help. 
I tried to do the exactly the same as shown in the above link, but it is giving me an error, like melt function is not working. I installed reshape2 package but still it is not working.

Thank You very much.

Comment: Hi, please post detailed information on the error you're getting and what you're seeing that's not working.

Comment: Dear Sir, sorry for late reply. it is saying (in rstudio software) ggplot function is not working and also melt function is not working. I a requesting you to guide from the beginning. I have given the link how I wanted the box plot. Pls help me sir. thanks my email is jaideepv1234@gmail.com (so I can send you my data)